# Ajax Call not being accessed in most pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cordova

This is a very weird problem but I will provide as much detail as possible. This Javascript function is in a separate .js file and referenced into various HTML pages in a Cordova application. When a push notification, with 2 parameters: id, type, is received into the device, a function called LaunchFromNotif is executed with these 2 parameters passed as arguments.

```
function LaunchFromNotif(id, type) {
try {
    var ebyidurl = url + "ReturnEByID";
    var nbyidurl = url + "ReturnNByID";

    if (type != null) {
        if (type == "n") {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: nbyidurl,
                data: { id: id },
                dataType: 'json',
                processdata: true,
                success: function (data) {
                    //code here
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    alert('Error: ' + error);
                }
            });
        } else if (type == "e") {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: ebyidurl,
                data: { id: id },
                dataType: 'json',
                processdata: true,
                success: function (data) {
                    //code
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    alert('Error: ' + error);
                }
            });
        } else if (type == "a") {
            combined(id);
        }
    }
} catch (exception) {
    //window.location = "Warning2.html";
}
}
```

Combined(id) is another function with 2 Ajax calls. I used when and then, to make sure that the first ajax call completes before starting the second.

```
function combined(id) {
alert("combined");
$.when(
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: nbyidurl,
        data: { id: id },
        dataType: 'json',
        processdata: true,
        success: function (data) {
            alert("success of first ajax");
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert('Error 1: ' + error);
        }
    })

).then(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: Verifytempurl,
        data: { Username: localStorage.getItem('user') },
        success: function (data) {
            alert("success of second ajax");             

        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert('Error 2: ' + error);
        }
    });

});
```

The problem is that this is working well in only one HTML page. In 3 other pages in which I tried, it shows the "combined" alert and seems to never access the Ajax call. The logic seems to make sense, especially since it is in working order in one page. What could normally go wrong in something of the sort? I am left with few debugging possibilities, especially since this is a Cordova app and being tested on mobile devices.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: But, when `type == 'e' or 'n'` you not call to `combined` function... Also, you are referencing jQuery into all html pages?

Comment: In all other 3 pages, can you check to see if you are getting right value in "nbyidurl" and "Verifytempurl" variables?

Comment: @lmfresneda yes I am only referring to the 'a' condition branch. the others are working fine. Yes I am referencing JQuery in all pages

Comment: @Rex Upon looking at it again, I am noticing that nbyidurl is not global! That could well be the problem! However, what does not really make sense, is the fact that it worked in one of the HTML pages. These 2 functions exist in the same script which is referenced in all pages, so strictly speaking, if it does not work in one of them, it should not work in any. Nonetheless, I will check tomorrow first thing and get back to you, as at this moment I do not have access to my working environment. Thanks!